# how to open main window(Dialer) from sub window(Chat)?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

Here is my code

**Main window**

```
class Ui_Form(object):

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(764, 719)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setKerning(False)
        Form.setFont(font)

if __name__ == "__main__":   
     import sys
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     Form = QtWidgets.QDialog()
     ui = Ui_Form()
     ui.setupUi(Form)
     Form.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**sub window**

```
class Ui_Chat(object):

    '''def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(Chat)'''

    def setupUi(self, Chat):
        Chat.setObjectName("Chat")
        Chat.resize(747, 711)
        Chat.setStyleSheet()
        self.back_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Chat_frame)
        self.back_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 51, 21))
        self.back_button.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/Images/arrow395.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.back_button.setIcon(icon1)
        self.back_button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        self.back_button.setCheckable(True)
        self.back_button.setAutoExclusive(True)
        self.back_button.setObjectName("back_button")
        self.back_button.clicked.connect(self.mainscreen)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Chat = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Chat()
    ui.setupUi(Chat)
    Chat.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Derived class**

```
from Dialer import Ui_Form
from chat import Ui_Chat

class DialerWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_Form,Ui_Chat):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
    def mainscreen(self):  
        Form=QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.Dialer=Form
        self.ui=Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(Form)
        self.Dialer.show()
```

this is my code for opening main window,but i am not getting output,this code is written in derived class,this derived class inherit both class properties of main window(Dialer) class and sub window(chat) class,basically i am using multiple inheritance,so  i calling this method from sub window which is parent for this class ,so i need expertise on this problem.

Comment: Is it really C# and C++?

Comment: There's no C++ or C# in this question, it all looks like Python.